# Mirror maker target topic name different from source topic name

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Is it possible to have a Kafka mirror maker that read from a source kafka cluster the data from a topic *source* and write those data to a target kafka cluster in a topic named *target*?

I was lookinkg around for some producer config properties in a mirror maker to specify the target topic name.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

to achieve this with MirrorMaker you need to create a custom MessageHandler in which you can perform the necessary transformations.

I have created an example at https://github.com/opencore/mirrormaker_topic_rename which might help you with this.

Let me know if you have additional questions.

Comment: More details about that was written in the blog: https://www.opencore.com/blog/2017/1/170131-mirrormaker-change-topic/